# Showing the graph boundaries in Matlab ezsurf

Tags: matlab

I am using this simple Matlab code to plot a 3d function. What is the best way to highlight the boundaries of the plot? (say by drawing a yellow line in the boundaries)

```
clc;
clear all;
syms x y;

func = x^2 + 4*y^2 - 2*x^2*y+4;
ezsurf(func, [-5,5]);
grid on;
box on;
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to highlight the edges of the domain, or the corners of the domain, or all the black lines on the surface?

Comment: @David I mean the edges of the domain. I edited my original post to make it more clear. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible just using the `hold on/off`:

1.Using **plot3**

```
clc; clear all;

syms x y;

func = x^2 + 4*y^2 - 2*x^2*y+4;
figure;
ezsurf(func, [-5,5]);
grid on;
box on;


hold on;
y1 = -5:0.1:5; x1 =  5.*ones(size(y1)); z1 =  x1.^2 + 4*y1.^2 - 2*x1.^2.*y1+4;
y2 = -5:0.1:5; x2 = -5.*ones(size(y2)); z2 =  x2.^2 + 4*y2.^2 - 2*x2.^2.*y2+4;
x3 = -5:0.1:5; y3 =  5.*ones(size(x3)); z3 =  x3.^2 + 4*y3.^2 - 2*x3.^2.*y3+4;
x4 = -5:0.1:5; y4 = -5.*ones(size(x4)); z4 =  x4.^2 + 4*y4.^2 - 2*x4.^2.*y4+4;

plot3(x1, y1, z1, 'y', x2, y2, z2, 'y', x3, y3, z3, 'y', x4, y4, z4, 'y');
hold off;
```

You can play with the LineWidth propriety to make this lines bigger.

Result:

[image]

2.Using **ezplot3** (parametric curves)

```
clear x y;
hold on;
x = {'5'; '(-5)'; 't'; 't'}; 
y = {'t'; 't'; '5'; '(-5)'}; 
for i = 1:size(x,1)
    funz = [char(x(i)),'^2 + 4*',char(y(i)),'^2 - 2*',char(x(i)),'^2*',char(y(i)),'+4'];
    h = ezplot3( char(x(i)), char(y(i)), funz, [-5, 5]); 
    set(h, 'Color', 'y', 'LineWidth', 2);
end
hold off;
```

Result:

[image]